# How do i make my index.html run a flash file that is on the same repository on Github?

Tags: html, github, actionscript, flash, flash-cs6

When I made a flash .swf file, I was told to publish it as a .html file as well with Adobe Flash cs6. I did, and when I went onto a web hosting site, all I had to do was upload the .swf file, and .html file. When I went onto my website, the flash file showed up perfectly.

Is there a way to do that in git hub as well?

Comment: Are you talking about [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)?

Comment: yes, its the one with username.github.io

Answer (score 0):

github is a website for managing software. The underlying technology is git.

You could use github to manage your flash and html files ( for example ) as you develop them.

Unless you want people to be able to access your source code ( if you make your github repository public ) then this is not really going to be any use to you, as its not a website hosting solution.

What do you want to do ? host your applications so people can access them as per a normal web server ? ( in which case github is not suitable ) or allow people to learn from the source code you develop or collaborate with other users to developer your applications ? ( in which case github is suitable )

Comment: I think that the feature is github pages as the above comment suggested, sorry for the confusion, I'm new to this stuff